# Why don't we have 33-bit CPUs?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, 32-bit

I have seen that CPU's and operating systems have moved upwards in terms of bits from 8-bit to 16-bit, to 32-bit and currently to 64-bit. I understand that this change is to increase the maximum amount of memory that is addressable by the CPU.

What I don't understand is why there is always a doubling of the bus size. Is it just an arbitrary/business decision to double the bus size or is there another reason?

Why can't we have a 33-bit CPU? Or if that wasn't enough, a 34-bit CPU? 64-bit seems like such a massive and unnecessary (expensive?) jump in address space and presumably complexity of the underlying silicon.

Comment: Because CPU designers work with binary systems which are based on powers of two. It's most efficient to double the size of instructions/bus/bandwidth when transistiong to the next stage.

Comment: @sawdust - Yet there's nothing that sacred about having a data path that is a multiple of 8 bits, and even less, having one that's some power of two multiple of 8 bits.

Comment: This question actually isn't that bad, and it isn't quite as simple as "oh well learn binary derp!", as Daniel (and my answer) points out. I'm gonna upvote it back to zero for that reason.

Comment: @DanielRHicks -- Yes, I remember the days of those bit-slice processors and mini-computers of various wordsizes.  The binary numbering system is the foundation of most digital computers, and is not mentioned as a topic that the OP does understand.  However I do share the OP's questioning of the "need" for 64-bit systems by most users (therefore I didn't downvote this question.)  I suspect that a lot of PC upgrading has been due to a "bigger is better" mentality rather than a demonstrated need.

Comment: It's not (just) about the memory addresses: 1. Using [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), 32 bit CPUs can address more than 4 GiB of memory. 2. Software that uses 64 bit integers/floating point numbers (e.g., media encoders, encryption software) may be almost twice as fast on a 64-bit CPU.

Comment: Your question contains a false premise. The increase in bit width was primarily to increase the width of general purpose registers. The increase in the width of pointers was historically secondary.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz (and others) Thanks, I forgot about the increase in size of the registers, I only considered the addressing space size increase, as that was the reason I moved to a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @sawdust I have a pretty good idea of how binary works, which is pretty obvious really from my question. No thanks for your unhelpful and rather rude response.

Comment: The x86-64 does not have a 64 bit address space. I think it depends on the model. This entry form my machine `address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual'. Therefore the most ram + memory mapped input/output this cpu could have is 64GB (though I know the max ram is 8GB for the system). Each "64bit" process can have a memory space of 48 bits, and each 32 bit process a memory space of (you guessed it) 32bit.

Comment: @Daniel Not 2^n × 8, it is just 2^n, as 8 is already 2^n. You could have 4, 2 or 1 bit. Also the “sacredness” is that sometimes you need to store a bit number. If a register is not of size 2^n, then the bit number will not fit comfortably into a sub-register. E.G if you have a 12bit register then the bits are 0…11, needing 4bits of storage, leaving the possibility of asking for bits 12…15 the CPU designer would have to define what should happen in these cases. This has happened in x86-64, the sub-registers are defined for upto 64bit addresses, and the current invalid values throw an exception.

Comment: @richard - As I said in my answer there have been CPUs with many different "odd" word sizes (and that's not even counting the decimal and centesimal systems of yore).  There's nothing to prevent someone from building a 53-bit processor, if that suits their requirements.  Yes, power of two designs are "prettier", but there's no great functional benefit.

Comment: @marshaul: This question was actually downvoted below zero? Why?? It's a good question! I think the downvoters probably had even less understanding of binary numbers than the question author.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: Yes, it was -1 around the time I posted my answer. Your thoughts echo my own.

Comment: Note: Most 64 bit processors only have a 48 bit bus. This may change once you don't need a rack of hard disks to hit 128 TiB (the limit of 48 bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 24, and 48-bit CPUs.  But with modern VLSI technology (or is it ULSI by now?), adding more bits to the data path is not that expensive.  Chip developers cram as much width onto the chip as possible, as that increases throughput with relatively little additional cost and with only a slight cycle time penalty.

Achieving more speed/throughput with a narrow data path and faster cycle time is much harder.

Comment: (Forgot to mention 60-bit CPUs -- The old CDC 6600 series.)

Comment: Even though this is an interesting answer, it still doesn't explain why powers of two seem to be preferred in modern PCs, which I think is what the question really aims at, even though not fully realized at the time of its creation.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye It is not so much powers of two as it is multiples of 8. A 32bit data bus can write exactly 4 bytes in one instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike many circumstances in a computer, for instance addressing, where increasing the address length by one bit increases the amount of addressable memory by a power of 2 (and why powers of 2 are so common in memory), the actual [word length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) of the CPU can be any convenient value.

The common word lengths for processors (16, 32, and 64 bits) came about actually as multiples of 8 (rather than powers of 2, although of course these particular multiples of 8 also happen to be powers of 2), 8 bits being the minimum size for a single [char](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type), itself the smallest commonly-used primitive data type.

Since 8 bits is itself too imprecise to be very useful for numeric values (or even for extended character sets such as UTF-16), words larger than 8 bits allow for much greater efficiency when working with values utilizing more than that many bits of precision, and multiples of 8 bits (the smallest commonly-used data type) are still the natural choice, allowing one to store an integer quantify of (e.g. 2, 4, or 8) chars in a word without leaving wasted, unused bits.

The wikipedia article on words has a section [Word size choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Word_size_choice) with ever so slightly more detail.

Comment: Not all multiples of 8 are powers of 2.

Comment: Excellent point, I really meant to say "these powers of 2". I'll make the fix.

Comment: There have been computers built with 6 and 10-bit "characters".

Comment: Sure, and again, the word length can be any convenient number, which needn't be based on character length or anything in particular. For instance, an ALU which rarely operated on "characters" would probably have a word length based on the least-precision integer commonly used. I didn't mean to suggest anything prescriptive, merely to explain the basic reason for the most common choices (and the ones he asked about).